# read boot sector using C on windows8

Tags: c, windows, operating-system, boot

i tried to read the boot sector using this program

```
int lire_secteur(int num_sect,unsigned char* buf)
{
int retCode = 0;
unsigned char secteur[512];
char disque[10]   ;
char partition ;
FILE* device ;
do
{
    disque[0]='\0'  ;       
    scanf("%c",&partition) ;
    if (partition=='0')
    {
        strcpy(disque,"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0") ;
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(disque,"\\\\.\\%c:",partition) ;
    }
    device = fopen(disque, "rb+");
}

while (device == NULL) ;
fseek( device,num_sect*512 , SEEK_SET );
if (fread (secteur, 512,1, device) < 1)
{
    printf("erreur\n");
    return 1 ;
}
else
{
    memcpy(buf,secteur, 512);
    retCode=0;
}
return retCode;
}
```

i have successfully read all sectors in the hard drive but when i want to read the boot sector i have this:
[image]

is the problem in my code or it'is due to windows8 ?

Comment: Are you sure that message isn't just part of the boot sector? (Maybe it gets printed if there's a disk read error, or if BOOTMGR is compressed and the uncompressor isn't installed)

Comment: This is the content of the boot sector. Did you expect something else?

Comment: @FUZxxl no i just want to confirm that this is the content :/ i did'nt like the error message

Comment: @AbderrahmaneMechri This error message is part of the boot sector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right result, that is the boot sector.
You might want to print it out formatted in hex rather than just a string like that as you'll be outputting random control characters to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a relatively old one but it does come up in searches)

Looks like the right data probably but to make any sense of it you'll need to parse it using NTFS header layouts.

See:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81456/An-NTFS-Parser-Lib
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfs-search/